# Using "called" with status and name

Tags: names

Let's say I have a sentence like this:

> I have participated in an event where I had to present myself to a European Commissioner called Jacques Santer.

Is it correct to use "called" in this sentence or is it okay to not use it? I personally feel like it sounds better without the word "called", but don't know how correct that is.

By the way, this has to be as formal as possible.

Comment: If you remove _called_, also remove the _a_ before _European_. You'll be left with a formal sentence where "European Commissioner" is Jacques' title.

Comment: Using _called_ instead of _named_ has a Gricean implicature that for all you know, the name is false. I.e, if all you can say is _called_ (hearsay) instead of _named_ (official), then you may have doubts; otherwise you'd use the neutral term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my edit of your sentence:

*I have participated in an event where I had to present myself to a European Commissioner, Mr. Jacques Santer.*

Since you want a formal sentence, it is best to give the honorific, *Mr*. or *Dr*. or *Professor*, as the case may be.

Using "he is called" to mean "his name is" is the polite form in many languages; it is rarely used by English speakers.

An example of "he is called", which sounds natural:  *Albert and Marianne named their son "Albert Paul".  The boy is called "Paul" rather than "Albert".*

Comment: And also the artist Jacopo Robusti, called _Tintoretto_.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another option is to switch the order of the name and title. Furthermore, changing "where" to "in which" and removing the "had to" make the sentence sound a little more formal. I agree with the answer above that adding "Mr." to the name gives the sentence formality and shows respect to the individual. After those changes, the sentence would sound like this:

**I have participated in an event in which I presented myself to Mr. Jacques Santer, a European Commissioner.**

Comment: I think "at which" might work better than "in which" in your suggested wording, but I share your view that "an event where" doesn't sound "as formal as possible," which is what the OP requested.